# Check even/odd for Palindrome?

Tags: python, testing, palindrome

Is it a good idea to check for odd/even length of a palindrome number/string? Most snippets I came across don't do this basic test. If length is even, it can't be a palindrome, no?

```
if len(var) % 2 != 0:
  # could be a palindrome, continue...
else:
  break
```

Or is it just better (i.e faster) to start comparing the first and last numbers/letters directly?

**Edit**: Okay, stupid question, should've thought twice! :)

Comment: Doc, note, I dissent! A fast never prevents a fatness,  I diet on cod.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[ABBA](http://www.abbasite.com/) - an example of [palindrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome) of four letters meaning even length.

> A **palindrome** is a word, phrase, [number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number), or other sequence of [characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_(symbol)) which reads the same backward or forward...

Comment: Also consider that if you repeat any word forward then backward, whether it has even or odd length, the combined word is going to have an even length, e.g. hello = helloolleh.

Comment: I would have never guessed this could be a valid answer to a programming related question.

Comment: @James "Dave Jarvis" modified the answer and placed a link, the original answer was quite meaningful.

Comment: Haha, my original answer formed an actual sentence, what have you done?!?  Nice link!

Comment: This should be in the running for "shortest accepted answer" award.

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way to check for a palindrome is to simply compare the string against it's reverse:

```
def ispalindrome(s):
   return s == s[::-1]
```

This uses extended slices with a negative step to walk backwards through `s` and get the reverse.

Comment: did you want two equal signs there (for a Boolean return values)? `return s == s[::-1]`

Comment: use == not =  (more characters to make stack overflow happy)

Answer (score 8):

baab = palindrome and has length of 4 which is even

Comment: no alternatively we could have baaaab - this is still a palindrome

Comment: **bb** is also a palindrome :-)

Comment: "b" is also a palindrome. "" is also a palindrome. Sheesh.

Comment: @John, "b" has odd length. Sheesh.

Comment: @Nick: Rewording: a palindrome can have any length (even 0).

Comment: Palindrome does not require even length, it just needs to read the same in both directions.  Sheesh.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome

Comment: @mynameiscoffey, that's why they also called crab inscriptions. Sheesh. :o)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
is_palindrome = lambda s : all(s1==s2 for s1,s2 in zip(s[:len(s)/2],s[-1:-(len(s)+1)/2:-1]))
```

only checks the front half with the back half, and short-circuits as soon as a mismatch is found.

Comment: This solution takes as much memory as @sth:'s much simpler implementation, is about 1/10th the speed, and says that "ab" is a palindrome. Here's a better solution with only fixed memory overhead: all(s[i]==s[-i-1] for i in range(len(s)//2)) . It's also faster than your example by about 20%.

Comment: Ouch!  My testing was a little *too* light - I've edited my answer to now fail on testing "ab".  My bias lately has been more for iterating over elements than for indexing using integer subscripts, I think I'll take a slightly different run at this using a generator that walks in from both ends of the string.

Comment: Try islice, izip and reversed? all(c1==c2 for c1,c2 in islice(izip(s, reversed(s)), 0, len(s)//2))

Answer (score 2):

Simple case: aa.

More complicated case: aaaa.

And so on.

Comment: Whenever I read "aa" I get a knee-jerk reaction to say "pahoehoe".

Answer (score 2):

If string.length is even Then : All chars count should be even, so we can not have a char with odd count.

If string.length is odd Then: One char count must be odd, so not all chars' count should be even.

--------------- I implemented the following JavaScript for the follow up roles :

```
function isStrPermutationOfPalindrome(_str) { // backward = forward
    var isPermutationOfPalindrome = true;
    var _strArr = [..._str];
    var _strArrLength = _strArr.length;
    var counterTable = getCharsTabularFrequencies(_str);
    var countOdd = 0;
    var countEven = 0;
    for (let [ky, val] of counterTable) {
        if (val % 2 == 0) {
            countEven = countEven + 1;
        } else {
            countOdd = countOdd + 1;
        }
    }
    if (_strArrLength % 2 == 0) {
        //Even count of all characters,otherwise false.
        //so can not have a character with odd count.
        if (countOdd != 0) {
            isPermutationOfPalindrome = false;
        }

    } else {
        //Odd count of 1 character
        //so not all chars with even count, only one char of odd count.

        if (countOdd > 1 || countOdd == 0) { //no odd, or more than one odd [ only one odd should be to return true]
            isPermutationOfPalindrome = false;
        }
    }
    return isPermutationOfPalindrome;
}


function getCharsTabularFrequencies(str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    var arr = Object.assign([], str);
    var oMap = new Map();
    var _charCount = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === ' ') {
            continue;
        }
        _charCount = 0;
        for (let j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            {
                if (arr[i] === arr[j]) {
                    _charCount = _charCount + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (i == 0)
            _charCount = _charCount + 1;
        if (!oMap.has(arr[i]))
            oMap.set(arr[i], _charCount)
    }
    return oMap;
}

let _str = 'tactcoapapa';
console.log("Is a string of '" + _str + "' is a permutation of a palindrome ? ANSWER => " + isStrPermutationOfPalindrome(_str));
```

Comment: Thank you for actually explaining the purpose behind counting even and odd characters

Answer (score 1):

Even length strings can be palindromes too. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome) doesn't say anything about this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

```
n=raw_input("Enter a string==>")
n=int(n)

start=0
term=n

while n>0:
    result=n%10
    start=start*10+result
    n=n/10

print start

if term==start:
    print "True"
else:
    print "False"
```